# TextIO.Read GCS folders into pipeline with past 30 days date as name

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to read a rolling window of past 30 days into my pipeline for e.g. on Jan 15 2017, I want to read:

```
> gs://bucket/20170115/* 
> gs://bucket/20170114/*
>. 
>.
>.
> gs://bucket/20161216/*
```

[This](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Read#from-java.lang.String-) says  ("*", "?", "[..]")  glob patterns are supported

[Similar question, but with no good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740610/how-to-specify-multiple-input-paths-to-a-dataflow-job)

I am trying to avoid doing 30 Text.IO.Read steps then Flattening all Pcollections into one, this causes hot shards in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading files from GCS, TextIO supports the same wildcard patterns as GCS, described here: [Wildcard Names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames).

In the answer for the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740610/how-to-specify-multiple-input-paths-to-a-dataflow-job), bullet #2 suggests forming a small number of globs to represent your full range:

> for example the two character range "23 through 67" is `2[3-]` plus
>   `[3-5][0-9]` plus `6[0-7]`

---

`TextIO` also has a new API [`readAll()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L211) which allows you to specify input files dynamically as data. This allows you to pass in the exact set of filenames you need:

```
private static List<String> generate30DayFileGlobs(DateTime now) {
  // ..
}

public static void main() {
  Pipeline p = // ..

  p.apply(Create.<String>of(generate30DayFileGlobs(DateTime.now())));
   .apply(TextIO.readAll());

  // ..
}
```

The new `TextIO.readAll()` API has not yet been released, but you can build from master by specifying the Beam artifact version `2.2.0-SNAPSHOT`. The 2.2.0 release [is in progress](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-beam-dev/201708.mbox/%3Ccf69b872-c5fb-aaa9-8225-39efd5947ede%40nanthrax.net%3E) and should be available sometime in September.

Answer (score 0):

One Glob Pattern generation function [here](http://meethassan.net/2017/09/13/reading-multiple-directories-in-dataflow-using-glob-pattern/)